# Popper.js not getting installed

Tags: angular, npm, popper.js

I recently created an angular project and am trying to install popper.js but not getting installed.

```
ng new <<project>>
cd <<project>>
npm install popper --save
```

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0
>
> (node_modules\rijs.resdir\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
>
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>
> fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>
> {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall
>
> spawn git npm ERR! path git npm ERR! errno ENOENT npm ERR! enoent
>
> Error while executing: npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t
>
> ssh://git@github.com/pemrouz/buble.git npm ERR! enoent npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT npm ERR! enoent This is related to
>
> npm not being able to find a file. npm ERR! enoent npm ERR! A complete
>
> log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! C:\Users\Mukesh
>
> Lekhrajani\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-02-19T10_09_53_537Z-debug.log

How can I install popperjs / popper.js using npm?

Answer (score 0):

As per their docs, popperjs should be installed using:

```
npm i @popperjs/core
```

or it you can use their CDN for runtime downloading by placing the script call in the `<HEAD>...</HEAD>` tag of your **index.html**:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
```

https://github.com/popperjs/popper-core